# Are there any events so rare that I can compare them to the odds of this event?

Tags: probability

I have calculated the likelihood of an event to be $1$ in $1.07 \times 10^{2867}$.

I'm looking for a way to describe to a layperson how unlikely this event is to occur, but the number is so mind boggling large I can't find a way to put it into words.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Winning the lottery every week for the next $x$ years?

Comment: Since the odds for Powerball are 1 in 175,223,510.00, and for assumptions sake it is played 52 weeks a year, what would X be?

Comment: $175223510^x = 1.07\times 10^{2867}\implies x \simeq 347$ (weeks) Winning the lottery every week for more than $6$ years. Looking from this perspective, it looks like the odds are not that bad :)

Comment: The calculation that led to the number is probably physically meaningless.

Comment: I'd like to get that lucky

Comment: It's equivalent to taking 1100 cards numbered 1-1100, thouroughly shuffling them for several hours, and then finding they're perfectly sorted in numerical order.

Comment: The volume of the observable universe times the estimated age of the universe measured in the fundamental unit of length/time (Planck length/time) is only about $5\times 10^{235}$. This universe is not big enough for this event to happen. You probably need $11$ more...

Comment: @AndréNicolas I don't understand the origin of your conclusion.

Comment: A probability calculation is build on a probabilistic model of a real situation. Mathematical models never fit reality perfectly, and many useful models do not even fit particularly well.

Answer (score 4):

It is the probability of the proverbial monkey hacking a typewriter and producing the first page of Hamlet.

Comment: This is a great answer, as there are about 10 letters and about 2867 letters on a page.  Compare with the probability of producing just the title, or the entire play.

Answer (score 0):

There's about $n=10^{80}$ atoms in the universe and about $p=4\times 10^{27}$ atoms in the human body. If you choose arbitrarily $p$ atoms in the universe, what is the probability that these atoms are exactly the atoms you are composed of at the instant you finish this sentence?

It's $\binom{n}{p}^{-1}$